# CSS: Bad text alignment when overflow is applied

Tags: html, css

The problem is when i want to display all the div content is not showing correctly, seems like the alignment is not working. Someone can help me to fix this issue? My current CSS snippet is this.

**HTML**

```
<section  id="32" class="products"  name="4"   company="1"> 
   <div class="product-header-container">
    <div class="title-product">
      <input id="32"  type="checkbox"  tax="0" value="1248" RangePricing="0" OrderNumber="56" name="Basic"  checked > <span class="title-product-value">   U.S. Maintenance Plan  </span>
    </div> 
    <div class="price-product">
      <span class="price-product-value">$1,248.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="description-product" hidden>Pays for the regular maintenance</div>      
    <div class="displayname-product">Pays for the regular maintenance</div>
  </div>

  <li class="bulletPoint">Oil &amp; Filter Replacement</li>
  <li class="bulletPoint">Tire Rotation</li>
  <li class="bulletPoint">Fuel Injection</li>
  <li class="bulletPoint">Breake Pads and Rental Car Allowance</li>
  <li class="bulletPoint">Service</li>

  <div class="icons-products">
    <a style="padding-right:5px;" id="modal1" class="linkmodal1 UsingWebService"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" ><i class="fa fa-cog" title="Options"></i></a>
    <a style="padding-right:5px;" id="modal2" class="linkmodal2"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" ><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" title="Brochure"></i></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.title-product {
    color: #41699A;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.price-product {
    float: right;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-top:5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    text-align: right;
}

.price-product-value {
    width: 45px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the width from `.price-product-value` ? As you have a fixed width and some prices may overflow it, if you have `overflow:auto`, it will show scroll bars. You can also try to change to `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: And please try to explain it better. What is exactly your problem? The scroll bar under some prices?

Comment: exactly that's the problem, the scrollbars and the alignment of the prices

Comment: Change `overflow:auto` to `overflow:hidden`

Comment: I dont want to hide the overflow, i just want to show the content and align vertical all the numbers :)

Comment: The numbers are aligned (to the right)! Your problem is the scrollbars. What happens when you remove the width from `.price-product`? I think that is your problem.

Comment: When i removed the `price-product` class this is the result, i think the problem is still the content, for example: the first 2 numbers overflow and the others is displaying all fine, here is the actual state

http://s21.postimg.org/8rt9skb0n/menu.jpg

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant to remove the `width` property from the `.price-product-value` class, so that the container uses a variable width, depending on the content. (actually you can remove the whole class and the span tag, they are not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Position `.product-header-container` relatively (i.e., `position: relative`).  Then, position `.price-product` absolutely (i.e., `position: absolute`) and set `.price-product` coordinates to something like `top: 5px` and `right: 5px`.  Play with it to place the price div in the top right corner.

Remove the `float`, `overflow`, and `text-align` from `.price-product`.  And you can just delete the `.price-product-value` class.  Also, the `span` within the `.price-product` is not necessary.